# Execute processes in parallel, wait and execute the others

Tags: makefile

I use the following code to execute targets in parallel. Now what I want that it will work in parallel but there is some targets that need to be executed at the end, like `wait` for 3 processes that run in parallel to finish and then execute another 2 processes. How can I do that?

For example here is `pack` and `cleanup` to *run after* `module1` and `module2` *will run in parallel*.

```
NPROCS = $(shell sysctl hw.ncpu  | grep -o '[0-9]\+')
MAKEFLAGS += -j$(NPROCS)
all: module1 module2

.PHONY: module1
module1:
    @echo "run module 1"
    DIR=$(PWD)
    @echo $(DIR)

.PHONY: module2
module2:
    @echo "run module2”
.PHONY:
pack:
   pack $(DIR)
cleanup: 
    gbt clean $(DIR)
```

Comment: @Biffen - sorry I dont understand, can you please provide the full answer as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what prerequisites, one of `make`’s great strengths, are for.

Change:

```
pack:
```

↓

```
pack: module1 module2
```

Which tells `make` that the `pack` target has two prerequisites; `module1` and `module2`.

This means `make` won’t run `pack` until both `module1` and `module2` have *finished* running. Whether they run in parallel won’t make a difference.

---

If you have a lot of prerequisites, you can put them in a macro, e.g:

```
modules = module1 module2 …

pack: $(modules)
```

Comment: thanks a lot, 1+ , this is the only way to do it ? since if I have a lot of pre-requisite I will end up with long line on the makefile target...

Comment: @shopiaT It’s not uncommon to put such things in macros (especially if the list is generated somehow), e.g. `modules = module1 module2 …`, `pack: $(modules)`.

Comment: can you please update with your answer ? I want to test it, and by the way it should be moduels `=` module1 ... or modules `=:` modules

Comment: @shopiaT `=` or `:=` would both work (in this case). Never `=:`. By now it sounds like you should peruse a `make` tutorial, or even [the GNU make documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html).